# Building Framework from a set of static libraries

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos, static-libraries, mac-frameworks

I have a set of static libraries (.a) and I want to make an OSX framework, which combines all of this libraries. Is it possible and how can I do that?

I cant just put this libraries to "Link binary with libraries" build phase in xcode because there are no dependencies to them, thats why they doesnt link with binary and just skipped..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been trying for about an hour, I don't think you really can. You can stick them together and include required headers, you may have to write all of the prototypes with the extern prefix so the compiler wont give warnings for implicit declarations. Here is an article on making static frameworks http://blog.cloudmade.com/2010/05/10/iphone-static-framework/